# Trying to get a UInt64 into a base32 string.....works in python not in vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net, base32

Hi Hope I can get an answer here to a stupid question.
Stupid because it's been explained to me & I still can't get it right.

```
Python Code:
sqln = 13173942528351756918
sqlid = ''
alphabet = '0123456789abcdfghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz'
for i in range(0, 13):
sqlid = alphabet[(sqln / (32 ** i)) % 32] + sqlid
RESULT: bdntyxtax2smq

vb.net code:
Dim sqln As UInt64 = 13173942528351756918 
Dim sqlid as string = ""
Dim alphabet as String = "0123456789abcdfghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz"
For iCount As Integer = 0 To 12
sqlid = alphabet((sqln / (32 ^ iCount)) Mod 32) + sqlid
Next iCount
RESULT: bfpuzytbx3s00
```

I suspect the reason the results are different is because vb.net returns a double when you call ^ and I should be "shifting" it but can't seem to work out the syntax (or find it)
Thanks for your time =+ ideas =+ help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time, you're dividing by 32<sup>iCount</sup> which is equivalent to shifting *right* by `5 * iCount`:

```
Dim sqln As UInt64 = 13173942528351756918UL
Dim sqlid as string = ""
Dim alphabet as String = "0123456789abcdfghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz"
For iCount As Integer = 0 To 12
  sqlid = alphabet((sqln >> (iCount * 5)) Mod 32) + sqlid
Next iCount
Console.WriteLine(sqlid)
```

Output:

```
bdntyxtax2smq
```

It sounds like it would be a good idea to read up on [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) :)

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!! You just helped me reverse engineer the Oracle SQL_ID used in all sorts of reports and joins. I can now improve the utility I'm writing for Oracle to convert SQL Text to the ID. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @GregSimpson: Not a problem - it's pretty rare for me to be able to help with VB problems :)